# Combine multiple lines based on column 1

Tags: linux, awk, multiple-columns

At present, I have this sample of data in test.csv:

```
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,16/Apr/2020
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,17/Apr/2020
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,18/Apr/2020
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,16/Apr/2020
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,17/Apr/2020
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,18/Apr/2020
    00085D20A469,8.8.8.8,16/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,16/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,17/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,18/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,8.8.8.8,16/Apr/2020
```

I have been using datamash to group based on column 1 (the MAC address), and analyse the IP addresses.

I can get it to look like the following outputs:

```
    datamash -st, -g1 unique 2 < test.csv
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,8.8.8.8
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,8.8.8.8

    datamash -st, -g1,2 count 2 < test.csv
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,3
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3
    00085D20A469,8.8.8.8,1
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3
    64167F801BF5,8.8.8.8,1
```

But, how can I get it to discard the top line that has no duplicate MAC, as there is only one IP address, and make an output that looks like the following?

```
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
```

Or this if there were 3 IPs..

```
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1,9.9.9.9,1
```

I want the lowest count to the left. I suspect awk can do this, but I have really struggled.

Comment: It's not clear why you have a single line of expected output at the bottom of your question that repeats the mac address on the line between 2 of the associated IP addresses when the first block of 2 lines of expected output doesn't do that. It's also not clear what `If want the lowest count to the left.` means. Simply post the output you expect to get from the input you posted.

Answer (score 0):

To collapse the values, you could take the output of your second command, change the first `,` to a different separator, e.g. `@` with `sed` and feed the output again into datamash and collapse on the second field (which is field2, field3 etc. combined).

```
$ datamash -st@ --output-delimiter=, -g1 collapse 2 \
  < <(datamash -st, -g1,2 count 2 < test.csv | sed 's/,/@/')
    0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,3
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
```

If you now want to remove the first entry which has three fields if I understood you correctly, you could use `awk` and print the lines with more than three fields:

```
$ datamash -st@ --output-delimiter=, -g1 collapse 2\
  < <(datamash -st, -g1,2 count 2 < test.csv | sed 's/,/@/') | awk -F, 'NF>3'
    00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
    64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes to download data from csv. I saved them to file fil1.txt so as not to obscure the solution.

Input data (fil1.txt):

```
0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,3
00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3
00085D20A469,8.8.8.8,1
64167F801BF5,4.3.2.1,3,3.3.3.3,2
64167F801BF5,9.9.9.9,1
0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,4
```

Awk script (fil1.awk):

```
// {
  if (l==$1) {
    print($0","r)
  }
  l = $1
  r = $2
}
```

Call:

```
cat fil1.txt |sed 's/,/ /' |awk -f fil1.awk
```

Output:

```
00085D20A469 8.8.8.8,1,1.2.3.4,3
64167F801BF5 9.9.9.9,1,4.3.2.1,3,3.3.3.3,2
```

Explanation:

```
// match to each line (default action) 
If (l == $1) checks if variable l is equal to first field ($1),
For 1 line in the txt file, l has no value so it bypasses the content of 
brackets {} and assigns the first field of the first line to variable l 
and the second field of the first line to variable r
For the second line of the txt file l and $1 are different, therefore 
body if is not performed again
For 3 line of the txt file l and $1 are the same:
print($0","r) prints the entire line 3 (field $0), a literal comma 
and the stored field 2 from the previous line.

and everything repeats for the next lines of the txt file
```

Just like you wanted in the commentary, version working for any number of sorted lines of repeated MAC addresses:

```
// {
  if (l == $1) {
  s = s","r
  }
  else {
    if (s != "") {
      printf("%s %s%s\n", l, r, s)
      s = ""
    }
  }
  l = $1
  r = $2
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do you mind explaining the awk script, please? And it could handle 3 or 4 entries for the same MAC address?

Comment: I simplified the script, added explanation, added script version for any number of lines with MAC repeated.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{ mac_ips[$1][$2]++ }
END {
    for ( mac in mac_ips ) {
        if ( length(mac_ips[mac]) > 1 ) {
            printf "%s", mac
            for ( ip in mac_ips[mac] ) {
                printf ",%s,%d", ip, mac_ips[mac][ip]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical SQL problem, so you can solve it using sqlite3 in linux. Give this a try.

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 << EOF
create table t1(id, ip_addr,dt);
.separator ,
.import $1 t1
select id, group_concat(ip_addr||','||c1) from (
select id, ip_addr, count(*) c1 from t1 where id in (
select id from ( select id, ip_addr, count(*) c from t1 group by id, ip_addr) t group by id having count(id) >1)
group by id, ip_addr )
group by id
;

EOF
$ cat ip.dat
 0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,16/Apr/2020
 0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,17/Apr/2020
 0004F2426603,74.214.224.150,18/Apr/2020
 00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,16/Apr/2020
 00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,17/Apr/2020
 00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,18/Apr/2020
 00085D20A469,8.8.8.8,16/Apr/2020
 64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,16/Apr/2020
 64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,17/Apr/2020
 64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,18/Apr/2020
 64167F801BF5,8.8.8.8,16/Apr/2020
$ a.sh ip.dat  # Execute a.sh by passing the file as parameter
 00085D20A469,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
 64167F801BF5,1.2.3.4,3,8.8.8.8,1
$
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly! I might need a full solution with standard commands, as I expect to analyse systems where I don't have the ability to install newer tools.